# Get current personal access token in Laravel sanctum from request

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-sanctum

I'm using Laravel Sanctum v3 in my Laravel project. I have an API controller which has the `auth:sanctum` middleware attached to it. I'm using the API key/plain access token that I copied to authenticate myself, but I need to retrieve the corresponding token itself.

I thought I could just do this from within my controller:

```php
return response()->json([
    'token' => Auth::user()->token
], 200);
```

This gives me:

> The attribute [token] either does not exist or was not retrieved for model

I also tried doing:

```php
PersonalAccessToken::find(Auth::id());
```

This gives me `null`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

to get the access token currently associated with the user

```
auth()::user()->currentAccessToken()
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you are looking for is `Auth::user()->tokens` which will return array of tokens to you. See the documentation : https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/sanctum#issuing-api-tokens

Answer (score 1):

You may access all of the user's tokens using the tokens Eloquent relationship provided by the HasApiTokens trait:

```
auth::user()->tokens
```

will return a collection of  tokens related to the auth user
if u don't   Create an access token  without a specific ability (Abilities serve a similar purpose as OAuth's "scopes")
u can just do like that

```
auth::user()->tokens->first() ;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have the name of the token, you can get it like this:

```
$user = Auth::user();   
$token = $user->tokens()->where('personal_access_tokens.name', 'your-token-name')->first();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for the Personal Access Token instance of the current request,

```
$currentRequestPersonalAccessToken = \Laravel\Sanctum\PersonalAccessToken::findToken($request->bearerToken());
```